# Как передать несколько полей ProfileFields в методе Users.Get (VkNet)?

Tags: c#, vknet

проблема заключается в следующем: вызываю метод Users.Get:

`var user = vk.Users.Get(new long[] { 11111111 }, ProfileFields.Online).FirstOrDefault();`

С этим проблем нет, но мне надо не только Online, как мне передать несколько полей?
Пробовал так, но не помогает:

`var user = vk.Users.Get(new long[] { 11111111 }, ProfileFields.Online).FirstOrDefault();
            var user1 = vk.Users.Get(new long[] { 11111111 }, ProfileFields.HomeTown).FirstOrDefault();`

Может, как-то можно передать сразу массив типа ProfileFields?

Comment: а такая возможность есть в самом АПИ сайта?

Comment: Ну должна быть.

Comment: ну тогда наверное можно его вызвать

Comment: "Его" - это кого?

Comment: метод в АПИ, который должен быть

Comment: Ну есть только такой метод.

Comment: вы можете вызывать только те методы, что есть в АПИ. Если нужный вам метод там есть - используйте его, если нет - то у вас нет возможности вызвать несуществующий метод.

Comment: `ProfileFields.Online | ProfileFields.HomeTown`

Comment: Alexander, спасибо! Правда, там возникла другая ошибка при авторизации, но она уже не касается этого вопроса.